# How to extract a text from column in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have data like:

```
COSM3755563_(COSMIC),_COSM3755562_(COSMIC),_rs16941_(Gene_file)
COSM148277_(COSMIC),_COSM3755561_(COSMIC),_rs16942_(Gene_file)
rs1060915_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes)
COSM3755560_(COSMIC),_rs1799966_(Gene_file)
rs206075_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes)
```

And I need an output like:

```
rs16941
rs16942
rs1060915
rs1799966
rs206075
```

I need just extract rs_number from this column. Problem is, that rs_number is allways on different position.

My solution was:

```
awk '{split ($1,arr1,"_"); print arr1[1)}' infile
```

This worked perfectly fine till changed position of my rs_number.

Appreciate any help in awk.

Comment: using the code you have, add a loop and look for `rs`, i.e. `awk '{n=split ($1,arr1,"_"); for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ if (arr1[i] ~ /^rs.*/)print arr1[i}}' infile` (There is probably a brace-mismatch which you will need to fix). Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `grep` to match the lines and only print the match,

```
$ grep  -o "rs[[:digit:]]*" file
rs16941
rs16942
rs1060915
rs1799966
rs206075
```

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Prints only the matching part of the lines.

---

This can also be done using `match` function in `awk`

```
$ awk  '{match($0, "rs[[:digit:]]*", arr); print arr[0]}' file
rs16941
rs16942
rs1060915
rs1799966
rs206075
```

Comment: this is nice grep implementation!

Comment: rs[[]:digit:] - this is what I was looking for! Amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Geroge You are welcome. Adding one more point, If you want to make sure that the `rs` is followed by at least one number, the regex could be better written as `rs[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*` as `*` matches zero or more. Hope it helps

Comment: It helps very well! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

I would use `sed` for that:

```
sed 's/.*\(rs[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' file
```

Search:

```
.*             - any character, zero or more times
\(             - begin of capturing group
rs             - the literal 'rs'
[[:digit:]]    - a digit ...
\{1,\}         - ... one or more times (can be \+ if you use GNU sed)
\)             - end of capturing group
.*             - any character, zero or more times
```

Replace:

```
\1             - Content of capturing group 1
```

Comment: Thank you for sed solution.. I have another post processing of this kind of text file all implement in awk.. So this is to reason to do this in awk.. But I like this solution!

Comment: `\+` instaed of `\{1,\}` looks better imo

Comment: @FloHe `\+` is not available in basic POSIX regular expressions.

Comment: Explanation in sed is very educated. Good to start study. Thank you!

Comment: @hek2mgl: If he uses (gnu) sed, which I suppose,  `\+` should work.

Comment: @FloHe Why do you suppose that the OP uses GNU sed and why should I make my answer specific to GNU sed without the need to? Believe me, it is not a good idea to use GNU additions in a SO answer because many people don't use GNU sed. I also had to learn that.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Ok, if that's the case, `\{1,\}` is the better choice for an answer.

Comment: @FloHe For the SO answer yes, I would say so. But just to make this clear, I'm not saying GNU additions shouldn't be used. I really like them and personally use them. I'd also like to see some of them making it into the POSIX standard, like `\+` for example. Let's see. :) (and waiiiiiiiiiiiit)

Answer (score 2):

Using awk :

```
awk 'match($0, /rs[0-9]+/) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH )}' data
```

This should not need `gawk` and should work even on older computers

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` based solution which uses an underscore character `_` as a field separator and prints fields that start with `rs`:

```
awk -F'_' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~/^rs/){print $i}}}' file
rs16941
rs16942
rs1060915
rs1799966
rs206075
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method also

```
 sed 's/.*\(rs[^\_]\+\).*/\1/' fileName
```

**Output:**

```
rs16941
rs16942
rs1060915
rs1799966
rs206075
```